# broke my python easy_install how to fix?

Tags: command-line, python

Any idea how to fix:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory
```

I kind of deleted it by accident before I realized that being behind a proxy was my issue not easy_install

Comment: You may know this, but many Python developers choose to leave the Mac OS X install of Python alone to avoid system issues. I currently install a separate copy via http://brew.sh

Comment: restore from backup or reinstall the OS, easiest get the combo upgrade and see if that fixes it

Comment: I agree, it can definitely be a pain to work with the system Python. My answer applies to both system-installed and external versions. It'll put setuptools in the site-packages directory of whatever python you use to run the setup script.

Answer (score 3):

`easy_install` is part of setuptools. There's a handy script to bootstrap it:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python
```

You may need to put `sudo` before `python` if it throws a permissions error. There's a few more details here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installation-instructions but that one-liner should do the trick in most cases.

Answer (score -3):

You can check this documents to fix easy_install in python.

Click on this link: [easy_install](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html)

Comment: Instead of sending people to yet another site please include the relevant parts directly into your answer.